# Managing SSRSreports in TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ssrs-2008

Is there a way to manage SSRS reports reports in TFS?

The SRSS and TFS servers are already installed and functioning. What I'm really looking for is to add a source control for "SRSS" in "TFS" so the report writers can use Visual Studio (2010) to checkout reports, make changes and check in. If source control is not possible, then what are my other options?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can export the report files and then put them in source control but as far as I know there is no way to get them into source control through visual studio (team explorer). You can add SSRS projects to source control from Visual Studio so if you move them into one of those you may find some luck. Out of the box there is no SSRS project.

Comment: is there a way to make TFS "import" reports from SSRS

Comment: By import I assume you mean some sort of gui? I haven't heard of one HOWEVER you can try this tool https://code.google.com/p/reportsync/ which will allow you to download .rdl files to your file system and then you can easily check them in (or add to an ssrs project for easy check in after that).